# Catch php querystring values from .aspx file

Tags: c#, php

I write a code to get parameters from SMS Gateway.But SMS gateway only accept php files.But our application is Asp.net, I wanted to get 4 parameters from gateway via php & send it to .aspx file.here is the scenario

[image]

Here i written the code for php file & aspx file.

PHP FILE

```
<?php
//Get Vidamo & Post aspx

$source  = isset($_GET['msisdn']);
$dest = isset($_GET['shortcode']);
$messageIn = isset($_GET['msg']);
$operatorNew = isset($_GET['operator']);

$source = $_POST['msisdn'];
$dest = $_POST['shortcode'];
$messageIn = $_POST['msg'];
$operatorNew = $_POST['operator'];

?>
```

Then i'm going to received it via .aspx file

```
        int source = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["msisdn"].ToString());
        int dest = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["shortcode"].ToString());
        string messageIn = Request.QueryString["msg"];
        string operatorNew = Request.QueryString["operator"];
```

I wanted to know using $GET i can received parameters via gateway & using $post can i send parameters via Query string or need any other steps to do..

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that what values are you getting in your variables in PHP file, Because isset function only returns true and false, Second thing is Query string only works with $_GET, You won't get data using Post if you are sending it via POST Method, If you want to retrieve this data in your .aspx file either you can pass data using **header** function in php OR You can Make one form in PHP File and 
onload post this form to your aspx file.

Comment: then how can  pass values to .aspx file

Comment: @ChathuraRanasinghe ya,the next step that i want actually.

Comment: as i said if you want to pass using query string then prepare URL like this yoursite.com/?msisdn=val&shortcode=val ans so on Now redirect to your URL using header function

Comment: Or if you want to post it then create a from and set velues you are getting in PHP file in element and onpage load Post this form to your url(aspx file)